# Установка npm для NodeJS

Tags: установка, веб-сервер

Как я понял, устанавливать npm для NodeJS обязательно. Вообщем, ввожу в консоле команду:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | shnpm install express
```

а в ответ:

> montytool# curlhttp://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh   %Total    % Received % Xferd  AverageSpeed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed100    85    0    85    0     0    1890 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   745Syntax error: newline unexpected

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быть внимательнее.

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh <html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>
```

Раз просит, так сделаем

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```